# Subscribing to an observable modified using .share() after it has disposed resources already

Tags: java, rx-java, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Here is the problem,

I have a network request which downloads some information. However, it is essential that this request is called only once during some period of time ( you will get the idea later on ) and all subscribers get the same result. My first thought was to use the `share()` operator, so it would multicast the result while keeping a single request source. But I am not sure what is going to happen if I try to subscribe to it again after the share operator already disposed the resources due to refCount dropping to 0.

The thing I am trying to accomplish here is that every request that I make, is dependent on the current state of information stored and those requests update this information. Once I make the first request, I need to keep a reference to it and inform every subscriber that subscribes until the time of request completion. After the request is finished, all subscribers gets their notification and unsubscribes... However, if there is a new subscription after the disposal I need it to repeat the request, thus resubscribing to the original source observable that was modified using `share`

Is something like this possible with simple `share` operator, or do I need to create a subject and control the emissions manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice library [RxReplayingShare](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare), which I think makes exactly, what you are trying to achieve.

It passes the same result to all `Subscriber`'s, when at least one is subscribed. When there are no subscribers anymore, the `Observable` completes. When subscribing again, the original `Observable` is called.

The [RxMarble](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare/blob/master/marbles.png) shows it better than the description.